# The reason why to use map twice for applying polars Rust

Tags: rust, rust-polars

```
let o = GetOutput::from_type(DataType::UInt32);
// this adds new column len, two is unchanged
let lf = lf.with_column(col("two").alias("len").apply(str_to_len, o));
```

```
fn str_to_len(str_val: Series) -> Result<Series> {
    let x = str_val
        .utf8()
        .unwrap()
        .into_iter()
        // your actual custom function would be in this map
        .map(|opt_name: Option<&str>| opt_name.map(|name: &str| name.len() as u32))
        .collect::<UInt32Chunked>();
    Ok(x.into_series())
}
```

This function works well.

```
fn str_to_len(str_val: Series) -> Result<Series> {
    let x = str_val
        .utf8()
        .unwrap()
        .into_iter()
        // your actual custom function would be in this map
        .map(|opt_name: Option<&str>| opt_name.unwrap().len() as u32) // <-- changed part
        .collect::<UInt32Chunked>();
    Ok(x.into_series())
}
```

But if I change the `map` part, like the above, the code is not available anymore.

And the rust analyzer said:

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `ChunkedArray<UInt32Type>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `u32`
    --> src/frag_feature_refiner.rs:70:10
     |
70   |         .collect::<UInt32Chunked>();
     |          ^^^^^^^ value of type `ChunkedArray<UInt32Type>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=u32>`
     |
     = help: the trait `FromIterator<u32>` is not implemented for `ChunkedArray<UInt32Type>`
     = help: the following other types implement trait `FromIterator<A>`:
               <ChunkedArray<BinaryType> as FromIterator<Option<Ptr>>>
               <ChunkedArray<BinaryType> as FromIterator<Ptr>>
               <ChunkedArray<BooleanType> as FromIterator<Option<bool>>>
               <ChunkedArray<BooleanType> as FromIterator<bool>>
               <ChunkedArray<ListType> as FromIterator<Option<Box<(dyn polars::export::arrow2::array::Array + 'static)>>>>
               <ChunkedArray<ListType> as FromIterator<Option<polars::prelude::Series>>>
               <ChunkedArray<ListType> as FromIterator<Ptr>>
               <ChunkedArray<T> as FromIterator<(Vec<<T as PolarsNumericType>::Native>, Option<Bitmap>)>>
             and 3 others
note: the method call chain might not have had the expected associated types
    --> src/frag_feature_refiner.rs:69:10
     |
64   |     let x = str_val
     |             ------- this expression has type `Series`
...
67   |         .into_iter()
     |          ----------- `Iterator::Item` is `Option<&str>` here
68   |         // your actual custom function would be in this map
69   |         .map(|opt_name: Option<&str>| opt_name.unwrap().len() as u32) // <-- changed part
     |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Iterator::Item` changed to `u32` here
note: required by a bound in `std::iter::Iterator::collect`
    --> /imbdx/user/eck/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:1892:19
     |
1892 |     fn collect<B: FromIterator<Self::Item>>(self) -> B
     |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Iterator::collect`
```

In this case, why I need to use `map` twice in the `str_to_len` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, `ChunkedArray` does not implement `FromIterator` for the `u32` type. `FromIterator` is, however, implemented for iterators whose elements are `Option<u32>` (see the [documentation](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/chunked_array/struct.ChunkedArray.html#impl-FromIterator%3COption%3C%3CT+as+PolarsNumericType%3E::Native%3E%3E-for-ChunkedArray%3CT%3E)).

Calling `.map` on an `Option` produces another `Option`, but `unwrap` extracts the value inside, so the iterator elements are no longer of type `Option`, causing `.collect` to fail.